# Wordpress Jobroller themes allow add multiple jobs?

Tags: wordpress

We used Jobroller themes.

this is working fine when user submit job then approve job then select plan for job and payment this is working fine.

but now we required that the user is submit job then approve then after user is allow to add again new job. like magento shopping cart that allow to add jobs and then payment all jobs to at a time.

it is possible